# How to add class name or style name to HTML tags generated with SQL 'FOR XML'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, vb.net, xquery

I have the below query to select the menu in a hierarchical way and display in asp.net web page,

In the output I'm getting `<li><a href="#">Products</a></li>`, I need to convert the output as below

`<li><a href="#" class="collapse"><i><img src="images/dashboard-normal.png"></i><span>Products</span></a></li>`

ie, I need to include class name, need to include image tag inside the li, need to add span tag (in my current output there is no class name, image tag)

Can anyone help me to achieve this please?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_menuXML( @IDMenuParent INT )
RETURNS XML
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT 
BEGIN RETURN 
(
SELECT 
    NavigateUrl AS "a/@href", 
    DisplayText AS "a", 
    CASE WHEN MenuParentID = @IDMenuParent
        THEN dbo.fn_menuXML( MenuID )
    END
    FROM SFM_Menu
    WHERE MenuParentID = @IDMenuParent
    FOR XML PATH('li'), ROOT('ul'), TYPE
)
END
GO

SELECT 
    NavigateUrl AS "a/@href", 
    DisplayText AS "a", 
    dbo.fn_menuXML(MenuID)
    
FROM SFM_Menu
WHERE MenuParentID =0 
    AND IsActive=1
ORDER BY DisplayOrder
FOR XML PATH('li'), ROOT('ul'), TYPE
```

Please find the schema and data below,

```
DECLARE @Menu TABLE
  (
    MenuID INT,
    MenuParentID INT,
    DisplayText NVARCHAR(100),
    NavigateUrl NVARCHAR(255),
    ImageUrl NVARCHAR(255),
    IsActive int,
    DisplayOrder bit
  );

INSERT INTO @Menu VALUES (1, 0, 'Products', 'Products.aspx','Sample.png',1,1) ,
                         (2, 1, 'Add Products', 'AddProducts.aspx','Sample.png',1,1),
                         (3, 1, 'Update Products', 'UpdateProducts.aspx','Sample.png',1,2),
                         (4, 1, 'Product Type', 'ProductType.aspx','Sample.png',1,3),
                         (5, 4, 'Logistics', 'Logistics.aspx','Sample.png',1,1),
                         (9, 0, 'Department', '#','Sample.png',1,2),
                         (10, 9, 'Clothing', 'Clothing.aspx','Sample.png',1,1),
                         (11, 9, 'Dresses', 'Dresses.aspx','Sample.png',1,1),
                         (12, 9, 'Accessories', 'Accessories.aspx','Sample.png',1,3),
                         (13, 0, 'Site Management', '#','Sample.png',1,3),
                         (14, 13, 'Security', 'Security.aspx','Sample.png',1,1) ,
                         (6, 4, 'Food Items', 'FoodItems.aspx','Sample.png',1,1),
                         (7, 6, 'Veg', 'Veg.aspx','Sample.png',1,1) ,
                         (8, 6, 'Non Veg', 'NonVeg.aspx','Sample.png',1,2) ;
```

Output should be like this,

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="Products.aspx" class="collapse">
            <i>
                <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
            </i>
            <span>Products</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="AddProducts.aspx" class="collapse">
                    <i>
                        <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
                    </i>
                    <span>Add Products</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="UpdateProducts.aspx" class="collapse">
                    <i>
                        <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
                    </i>
                    <span>Update Products</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="ProductType.aspx" class="collapse">
                    <i>
                        <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
                    </i>
                    <span>Product Type</span>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="Logistics.aspx" class="collapse">
                            <i>
                                <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
                            </i>
                            <span>Logistics</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="FoodItems.aspx" class="collapse">
                            <i>
                                <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
                            </i>
                            <span>Food Items</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="Veg.aspx" class="collapse">
                                    <i>
                                        <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
                                    </i>
                                    <span>Veg</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="NonVeg.aspx" class="collapse">
                                    <i>
                                        <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
                                    </i>
                                    <span>Non Veg</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="collapse">
            <i>
                <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
            </i>
            <span>Department</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="Clothing.aspx" class="collapse">
                    <i>
                        <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
                    </i>
                    <span>Clothing</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Dresses.aspx" class="collapse">
                    <i>
                        <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
                    </i>
                    <span>Dresses</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Accessories.aspx" class="collapse">
                    <i>
                        <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
                    </i>
                    <span>Accessories</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="collapse">
            <i>
                <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
            </i>
            <span>Site Management</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="Security.aspx" class="collapse">
                    <i>
                        <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png" />
                    </i>
                    <span>Security</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perhaps a SQL replace function may be able to do the trick, replace the href hashtag with its value and append the class and other tags you need.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: The desired output (X)HTML is not well-formed. Please fix it too.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I have added data and schema as per your comments, thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just return the data from the database and use asp.net to create the html from that? Then each part does what it does best

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I'm getting correct data from this query, so I just need to add class name, additional html inside <a> tag, So I can directly display it in page using <literal> tag. If there is a way then it would be better to do from SQL query itself.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

It is using a recursive CTE to construct a menu based on the specified parent node.

It is not clear where to get the images link.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @Menu TABLE
(
    MenuID INT,
    MenuParentID INT,
    DisplayText NVARCHAR(100),
    NavigateUrl NVARCHAR(255),
    IsActive int,
    DisplayOrder bit
);
INSERT INTO @Menu VALUES 
(1, 0, 'Products', 'Products.aspx',1,1) ,
(2, 1, 'Add Products', 'AddProducts.aspx',1,1),
(3, 1, 'Update Products', 'UpdateProducts.aspx',1,2),
(4, 1, 'Product Type', 'ProductType.aspx',1,3),
(5, 4, 'Logistics', 'Logistics.aspx',1,1),
(9, 0, 'Department', '#',1,2),
(10, 9, 'Clothing', 'Clothing.aspx',1,1),
(11, 9, 'Dresses', 'Dresses.aspx',1,1),
(12, 9, 'Accessories', 'Accessories.aspx',1,3),
(13, 0, 'Site Management', '#',1,3),
(14, 13, 'Security', 'Security.aspx',1,1) ,
(6, 4, 'Food Items', 'FoodItems.aspx',1,1),
(7, 6, 'Veg', 'Veg.aspx',1,1),
(8, 6, 'Non Veg', 'NonVeg.aspx',1,2);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @IDMenuParent INT = 0;

-- Find all child nodes of the specified parent node
-- just to see
;WITH Hierarchy AS
(
    SELECT Path=CAST(T1.DisplayText + '/' AS VARCHAR(1000)), Level=1, T1.MenuID,T1.MenuParentID,T1.DisplayText, T1.NavigateUrl 
    FROM @Menu T1
    WHERE T1.MenuParentID = @IDMenuParent
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Path=CAST(TH.Path + T1.DisplayText + '/' AS VARCHAR(1000)),Level=TH.Level+1, T1.MenuID,T1.MenuParentID,T1.DisplayText, T1.NavigateUrl
    FROM @Menu T1 INNER JOIN 
        Hierarchy TH ON TH.MenuID = T1.MenuParentID
)
SELECT * FROM Hierarchy
ORDER BY MenuID; 

-- real deal
;WITH Hierarchy AS
(
    SELECT Path=CAST(T1.DisplayText + '/' AS VARCHAR(1000)), Level=1, T1.MenuID,T1.MenuParentID,T1.DisplayText, T1.NavigateUrl 
    FROM @Menu T1
    WHERE T1.MenuParentID = @IDMenuParent
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Path=CAST(TH.Path + T1.DisplayText + '/' AS VARCHAR(1000)),Level=TH.Level+1, T1.MenuID,T1.MenuParentID,T1.DisplayText, T1.NavigateUrl
    FROM @Menu T1 INNER JOIN 
        Hierarchy TH ON TH.MenuID = T1.MenuParentID
)
SELECT (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Hierarchy
    ORDER BY MenuID
    FOR XML PATH('li'), TYPE, ROOT('ul')
).query('<ul>
{
for $x in /ul/li
return <li>
    <a href="{$x/NavigateUrl}" class="collapse">
        <i>
            <img src="images/dashboard-normal.png"/>
        </i>
        <span>{data($x/DisplayText)}</span>
    </a>
</li>
}
</ul>');
```

Comment: Thank you, this is correct. But <DisplayText> around the text is not required, instead I need       <span>Department</span>, so how can I do this? replace the text or any other options??
As of now it is coming like this, <span>
        <DisplayText>Department</DisplayText>
      </span>

Comment: I fixed it. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you, the formation is correct now, but the hierarchy is not coming, under product there should be Add Products, Update Products and product type. In my query the hierarchy is correct but this formation is not there, If you don't mind could you check that please?

Comment: I already asked you to provide a minimal reproducible example ##1-4. The #3 is missing. Overall, I think that the **sort order** should be somewhat different.

Comment: I am guessing again, but you can try just `ORDER BY MenuID`. That's why I kept the first `SELECT ... ` -- with just to see comment.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have added the output hierarchy format to the question for better understanding.

Comment: I adjusted the sort order in the answer. Please give it a shot.

Comment: @RageshSivakumar, what's the latest on your end?

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your response, The menu order is correct but the hierarchy is not coming. I have added the image column as well as the required ul li output.  I was supposed to reply you by yesterday, but due to some work I could not do that. Thank you

Comment: Finally, you produced the #3, i.e. desired output. I doubt that it is possible to construct such XML via SQL Server XQuery capabilities.

Comment: Oh, ok then I'll create this using vb.net, Could you suggest any books or site or video for expertizing SQL ?  Also could you give an up vote for this question?

Comment: I up-voted your question